# Is it possible to add new data with new class/label in python sklearn or other libraries?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, weka, pmml

I have the following code for simple classification, using sklearn linear_model SGDClassifier:

```
import numpy as np 

from sklearn import linear_model 

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]]) 

Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2]) 

clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier() 

clf.fit(X, Y) # Train the model for the first time. 
 
X_new = np.array([[-1.2, -0.4], [2, 1.9], [-1, 1], [1, 2]]) 

Y_new = np.array([3, 3, 4, 4]) 
 
clf.partial_fit(X_new, Y_new)
```

I need to add new class, but getting the following error:

```
ValueError: classes should include all valid labels that can be in y
```

How can I add new classes and use the already trained classifier?

Comment: You can't. A classifier is trained on a subset of data that is supposed to be representative of the real data. If you want new classes, you need to get a  new dataset and retrain the classifier.

Comment: thankyou - is there any other libraries to do this?